# Collection was modified, enumeration operation may not excute in Moq with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, in-memory-database

While doing unit testing, i am not able to get collection back from dbset after add new entity in dbset, it throw an exception '**Collection was modified**'

Here is my code setup

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("Skill Category")]
public void Create_Skill_Category()
{
    var category = new SkillCategoryModel() { CategoryId = 3, CategoryName = "Category 3" };
    var result = skillManager.SaveSkillCategory(category);
    Assert.IsNotNull(result, "Category can't be null");
    Assert.AreEqual(category.CategoryId, result.CategoryId, "Category id must be equal");
    var categoryList = skillManager.GetCategories(); // here exception thrown
    Assert.IsTrue(categoryList.Count == 3, "Categories List must be contain three category");
}


private ISkill skillManager;
[TestInitialize]
public void Init()
{
    var category = new SkillCategory { CategoryId = 1, CategoryName = "Category 1" };

    var categories = new List<SkillCategory>
    { 
        category,
        new SkillCategory { CategoryId = 2, CategoryName = "Category 2" }
    };
    var categoryMockSet = Utility.GenerateMockEntity(categories);
    categoryMockSet.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<SkillCategory>())).Callback<SkillCategory>(x => categories.Add(x)).Returns<SkillCategory>(x => x);
    var mock = new Mock<WhoEntities>();
    mock.Setup(q => q.SkillCategories).Returns(categoryMockSet.Object);
    mock.CallBase = true;
    skillManager = new WhoGroup.DML.Managers.SkillManager(mock.Object);
}
```

here I'm not able to understand what I do wrong in this case.
for reference I'm using this link:

[Entity Framework 6 and Moq4: Is it possible to have a mocked DbSet retain added data for the duration of its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24258910/entity-framework-6-and-moq4-is-it-possible-to-have-a-mocked-dbset-retain-added)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The following statement is not correct:**

```
entityMockSet.As<IEnumerable<TEntity>>()
    .Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(query.GetEnumerator());
```

The same `Enumerator` is returned for every request, which leads to the problem that you can use the enumerator only **once** because it has no items in it after.

What partially fixes the problem is resetting the enumerator every time when calling the `GetEnumerator` which solves it for you because you may only use the `Add`-Method

**Solution:**
What really fixes the problem is to use a Lambda when setting up the GetEnumerator Method:

```
entityMockSet.As<IEnumerable<TEntity>>()
    .Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => query.GetEnumerator());
```

This part is very important:
`.Returns(`**() =>** `query.GetEnumerator());`
Because with this a new Enumerator gets returned every time a request is made.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked after added only () =>.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurred in moq Dbset because I m not updating the reference of GetEnumerator after adding new Entity in DB set.

```
 public class Utility
    {
        public static Mock<DbSet<TEntity>> GenerateMockEntity<TEntity>(List<TEntity> entityList) where TEntity : class
        {
            var list = new List<TEntity>();
            list.AddRange(entityList);
            var query = list.AsQueryable();
            var entityMockSet = new Mock<DbSet<TEntity>>() { CallBase = true};
            entityMockSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(query.Provider);
            entityMockSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(query.Expression);
            entityMockSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(query.ElementType);
            entityMockSet.As<IEnumerable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(query.GetEnumerator());
            entityMockSet.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<TEntity>())).Callback<TEntity>(x => {
                list.Add(x);
                entityMockSet.As<IEnumerable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(list.GetEnumerator());
            }).Returns<TEntity>(x => x);
            return entityMockSet;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works only if you only use the Add method, and don't do any other foreachs or similiar over the collection