# SQL Lite throwing "System.NotSupportedException for Time Data Type in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, c#-4.0

I am currently using  SQL lite 1.0.97 Package  (new to sqlite) with EF6 to run my unit test and ran into a problem with `Time` Datatype in SQL. It is reporting an error -

> System.NotSupportedException: There is no store type corresponding to the EDM type 'Edm.Time' of primitive type 'Time'.

I do not want to change the data type in EF domain entity. Is there any other workaround for this ?

Answer (score 0):

It is shortfall of SQLite for Datetime or Time data type. Insertion and updation is occurred in easy way but selection is not easy.